# Roman wedding congratulations

Tags: idiom, passage-request, roman-culture

How did the Romans congratulate a couple on their wedding day?
The concepts of wedding and marriage were not quite what they are now back then, but I assume that celebrations and congratulations were not unheard of.

I can think of many possible nice things to say and I can put them in Latin, so the focus is on attested, especially multiply attested if any, congratulations.

I am currently on my way to a wedding, but this question is not urgent as the couple appears not to be very fluent in Latin and might not appreciate its use quite enough.
(Note added later: No Latin ended up being used at the wedding.)

Answer (score 5):

Roman weddings, although merry, were somewhat more solemn than modern ones and the central aspect were serious hymns. There is a work by Ausonius called *Cento Nuptualis* in which a wedding is described. In that work, some things that are said are:

*O digno coniuncta viro, gratissima coniunx, sis felix, primos Lucinae experta labores et mater!*

*Fortunati ambo, si quid pia numina possunt, vivite felices!*

In the *Trinummus* by Plautus there is a wedding and the celebrants are addressed in the following way:

*Di fortunabunt vostra consilia*

Also, a very standard expression is the following:

*Di tibi bene faciant.*

Comment: Link to the relevant page in Ausonius: https://books.google.cl/books?id=rtKwEAAAQBAJ&pg=PR340&lpg=PR340&dq=O+digno+coniuncta+viro,+gratissima+coniunx,+sis+felix,+primos+Lucinae+experta+labores+et+mater&source=bl&ots=z4HbL9bxkI&sig=ACfU3U1Z-IZG8DWkCGWqe6na549wvfktlA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL1Lf_moKCAxVfhIkEHRSkCnUQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=O%20digno%20coniuncta%20viro%2C%20gratissima%20coniunx%2C%20sis%20felix%2C%20primos%20Lucinae%20experta%20labores%20et%20mater&f=false

Comment: The work is called [Cento Nuptialis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Aus.%20Cent.%20Nupt.%206), and the full citation is Aus. Cent. Nupt. 6.

Comment: @Rafael There is a chapter of that work that is named the Cena Nuptualis, but I have changed the title to that of the overall work.